# Doctrine repostiory does not refresh its state in functional test

Tags: php, symfony, transactions, doctrine, api-platform.com

I'm learning how to write test for my Api Platform based api. I'm using Alice helper `RefreshDatabaseTrait` in test class. In documentation it says that this trait wraps every test is transaction and when its done just rolls its back. Because of that when I for example delete Employee using HttpClient and want to assert it was deleted I have to initialize `EmpoyeeRepository` again in order for test to pass. If i don't do it 'count()' method returns 10 Employees. Is there a problem with nested transactions or something?

```php
class EmployeeTest extends AbstractTest
{
    use RefreshDatabaseTrait;

   /** @test
     * @group functional
     */
    public function deleteEmployee(): void
    {
        // Arrange
        /** @var EmployeeRepository $employeeRepository */
        $employeeRepository = static::getContainer()->get(EmployeeRepository::class);
        /** @var Employee $employee */
        $employee = $employeeRepository->findOneBy([]);

        // Act
        $this->createClientWithCredentials()
            ->request('DELETE', '/employees/' . $employee->getUuid());

        // Assert
        $employeeRepository = static::getContainer()->get(EmployeeRepository::class);

        static::assertResponseIsSuccessful();
        static::assertEquals(9, $employeeRepository->count([]));
    }
}
```

```php
class AbstractTest extends ApiTestcase
{
    private ?string $token = null;

    /**
     * @throws \JsonException
     */
    protected function createClientWithCredentials($token = null): Client
    {
        $token = $token ?: $this->getToken();

        return static::createClient([], ['headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json']]);
    }

    /**
     * Use other credentials if needed.
     * @throws \JsonException
     */
    protected function getToken($body = []): string
    {
        if ($this->token) {
            return $this->token;
        }

        $response = static::createClient()->request('POST', '/token', ['json' => $body ?:
            [
                "email" => "admin@email.com",
                "password" => "pass"
            ]
        ]);

        static::assertResponseIsSuccessful();

        return json_decode($response->getContent())->token;
    }
}
```

Api Platform 2.6.8, Symfony 6.0, Hautelook/Alice 2.11 Doctrine/orm 2.13.1

Answer (score 0):

you dont state why you reinit the `EmployeeRepository`. if you don't then what? you still get the old employee returned?

without knowing further details I will probably assume that it MIGHT be a caching issue.

Repositories or actually more specifically entitymanager keeps a cache that is a bit brittle I have noticed.

Try clearing it

`$employeeRepository->getEm()->clear();` where getEm is a custom function that returns the `EntityManager` `$_em` from the repo.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. If I reinit `EmployeeRepository` and call 'count()' method on it it will return expected amount of Employees which should be 9. If i don't do it test will fail because it will return 10. Unfortunately clearing cache does not help.

Comment: this is a api platform apitestcase right? I havent used those before. If you delete via Repository directly, without request, it does work fine, right? looks like you have to debug this one yourself... my setup is too different. It must be a caching issue... or a bug at worst.

Comment: is this is a panther test there might be an issue as the process of panther runs in a different process. Transactions only work in ONE process, if you have multiple, it wont understand the changes to be in the same transaction.

Comment: I'm using ApiTestCase. Deleting through repository works and i don't know what to think about it because clearing cache didn't help.

Comment: I would try to search for issues here https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues?q=apitestcase and if nothing is found, go to the symfony slack channel and raise your concern there. Be sure to join the channel of api platform if it exists. Learn how to browse for slack channel inside it. If that doesnt help, raise an issue on github

Comment: Okay if I first create some variable $client with `createClientWithCredentials()` and then use `request()` method it works. I found this by recreating this test but with WebTestCase and if ill try to do this in same line it throws me: `LogicException: Booting the kernel before calling "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase::createClient()" is not supported, the kernel should only be booted once.` So probably ApiTetsCase does not have that check and I have booted Kernel more than once?

Comment: oh, great! well... check `createClientWithCredentials()` implementation. In php all source files can be easily read right? just read what they wrote there and if they create another kernel

Comment: And be sure to add a github issue if it is actually that issue. You can terminate a kernel as well somehow, I think with `$this->ensureKernelShutdown()`

Comment: createClientWithCredentials() is my method. It just returns this: `static::createClient([], ['headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json']]);` so its using ApiTestCase createClient implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem:

```php
public function deleteEmployee(): void
{
    // Arrange
    //getContrainer is booting Kernel
    /** @var EmployeeRepository $employeeRepository */
    $employeeRepository = static::getContainer()->get(EmployeeRepository::class);
    /** @var Employee $employee */
    $employee = $employeeRepository->findOneBy([]);

    // Act
    // This method boot's another Kernel!
    $this->createClientWithCredentials()
        ->request('DELETE', '/employees/' . $employee->getUuid());

    // Assert
    $employeeRepository = static::getContainer()->get(EmployeeRepository::class);

    static::assertResponseIsSuccessful();
    static::assertEquals(9, $employeeRepository->count([]));
}
```

So it appears that you cannot boot kernel more than once.

Comment: please try to shutDown the first kernel and see if that solves the issue... so you can actually get a solution together

Comment: Ok you are right, if i do this I get and exception: `LogicException: Cannot retrieve the container from a non-booted kernel.` So this is not the full picture. What is even better when I move createClient() on top of the test this exception is not thrown.

Comment: actually bootKernel does a shutDown itself in the createClient function. At this point I would just... create the client at the top. Then call `->request()` separately. And remember to always create client at the very top.  And recall everything becomes stale once you need a new client.